# Follow links with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I know how to find the links on a specific page with regular expressions:

```
import urllib2
import re

url = "www.something.com"

page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

html = page.read()

links = re.findall(r'"((http|ftp)s?://.*?)"', html)
```

However, I can't figure out how to follow the links to extract say the `<p>` tags. I tried this:

```
for link in links:
    page += urllib2.urlopen(links)
    html += page.read()

paragraphs = re.findall(r'(<p(.*?)</p>)', html)

for paragraph in paragraphs:
    print paragraph[0], "\n"
```

How is it supposed to be done?

(Sidenote: This is a regex question, not a BeautifulSoup question.)

Comment: "Sidenote: This is a regex question, not a BeautifulSoup question." <- Yes, but *why*?

Comment: What do you mean by follow the links to the tags? Are you trying to parse html with regex?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just have some small syntax errors in your code snippet.  When you use `re.findall`, it “captures” expressions in parentheses as groups and returns them as part of each hit.  Thus, your `links` list (get it?) is not a an array of strings, but an array of tuples.  e.g.,

```
('https://s.yimg.com/os/mit/ape/w/d8f6e02/dark/partly_cloudy_day.png', 'http'), ('https://s.yimg.com/os/mit/ape/w/d8f6e02/dark/mostly_cloudy_day_night.png', 'http')
```

So you can just update your for loop to ignore the second part of the tuple by:

```
for link, _ in links:
    page += urllib2.urlopen(link)
    html += page.read()
```

n.b. You also had a typo in the spelling of `link` (you had `links`).  The same thing goes for the paragraphs where the parentheses delineate saved groups.

Comment: I get "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'instance' and 'instance'" in response to "page += urllib2.urlopen(link)".

Comment: Well, that’s the problem with using `re` and not `beautifulsoup`.  You might easily be trying to follow `img.src` and `form.action` properties.